# How to remove error, probably caused by STRING VARIABLE with single quotes put in SQL statement ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, concatenation, quotes

My program results in errors when I put these set of numbers enclosed in single quotes

`string sql1 = "( 11111111111111, 222222222222 )";`

into a string variable and use that variable in an SQL statement.

I am using the `AND COLUMN_NAME IN ( '" + sql1 + "' )`.

I receive the following errors:

> SQL exception was unhandled by user code: incorrect syntax near ‘11111111’  or  Incorrect syntax near ‘(‘.

I will use that query in an SQL adapter and use the Fill command to fill a DataTable.

If I use the method `DoQuotes`, instead of the string variable, to replace the single quote with 2 single quotes,  it doesn’t error but the CSV file generated has NO data.

My program generates a CSV file report.

SQL Code: `AND CARD_NMBR IN (  '" + DoQuotes(sql1) + "' )  ";`

Which is

```
public static string DoQuotes(string sql)
    {
        if (sql == null)
            return "";
        else
            return sql.Replace("'", "''");
    }
```

Even if I switch to removing and adding the parenthesis in the string variable or in the SQL statement itself, it produces an error.  Code: `string sql1 = " '22222222222222', '333333333333333333' ";` (no parenthesis)

Here are more of my code.

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asccendConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open(); 
    string sql1 = "( '111111111111', '2222222222222' )";
    string query = " select bla bla bla from bla where colum_name = abc AND Card_NBR IN ( '"+sql1+"' );

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        a.Fill(t1);    //here it errors (see the picture above with link) 
    }
    return t1;
    ///below here is fine, no errors

     protected void btnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    var dataTable = GetData();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> rows = new List<string>();

    StringBuilder builderColumn = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        columnNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
    }

    builder.Append(string.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray())).Append("\n");

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        List<string> currentRow = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            object item = row[column];

            if (column.Ordinal == 3)
                currentRow.Add("'" + item.ToString());
            else
                currentRow.Add(item.ToString());

           }

        rows.Add(string.Join(",", currentRow.ToArray()));
    }

    builder.Append(string.Join("\n", rows.ToArray()));

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ACTIVATION_REPORT.csv");
    Response.Write(builder.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss one `"` in this part of your code:

`AND Card_NBR IN ( '"+sql1+"' );`

this should be

`AND Card_NBR IN ( '"+sql1+"'");`

Answer (score 1):

You are having extra set of single quote in

```
Card_NBR IN ( '"+sql1+"' );
```

Change it to

```
Card_NBR IN ( "+sql1+" )";
```

**You should  use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)**, that will save you from [SqlInjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well as remove these problems.

Also your your first condition should have `abc` enclosed in single quotes

```
where colum_name = 'abc'
```

with SqlParameter it should be like:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
string query = " select bla bla bla from bla where colum_name = @parameter1 AND Card_NBR IN ( @parameter2)";
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", "abc");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter2", "'22222222222222', '333333333333333333'");
//attach connection... REST of your code
}
```

Comment: @Christian Mark:  i dont know why i should do that, I had other codes and works with just  `( '"+sql1+"' );`

@Ahmed: sorry typo when i copy pasted to stack exchange but in my real code its fixed

@Habib: Changing to` Card_NBR IN ( "+sql1+" )";`  worked!  However I cannot use sqlparameter because actually those numbers are to be entered 
in a textbox, and I dont know how many, so they are dynamic. 
Or should it look like this:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter2", "'+number1+"', "'+number2+"' ");`

BTW thanks to all that helped! Thank you so much

Comment: @MikkoFullero, use SqlParameter and supply it any string, like the one in your example.

Comment: @MikkoFullero, also consider posting separate comment on each one's respective posts

Answer (score 0):

Theres a closing quote missing at the end of

```
string query = " select bla bla bla from bla where colum_name = abc AND Card_NBR IN ( '"+sql1+"' );
```